# TypeError: value.toString is not a function from node-input-validator on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

So I have been getting the error on a post request endpoint of mine and it shows that it is from the dependency "node-input-validator" which I used for validation. But this works perfectly in another Heroku account I deployed to and works locally on my machine. I just don't really understand why this error occurs. Also, this error started occurring after I upgraded to the Heroku-22 stack. Below is the error snippet.

```
2022-07-17T07:10:37.706093+00:00 app[web.1]: OPTIONS /v1/auditions/62b4def93aafc20074636f4f/enlist/entries 204 0.146 ms - 0
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127600+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:114) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: value.toString is not a function
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127608+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.reallyEmptyTrimmed (/app/node_modules/node-input-validator/lib/util/empty.js:14:17)
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127608+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.required (/app/node_modules/node-input-validator/lib/rules/required.js:4:13)
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127609+00:00 app[web.1]: at Validator.apply (/app/node_modules/node-input-validator/lib/validator.js:356:33)
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127609+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/node-input-validator/lib/validator.js:209:29
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127610+00:00 app[web.1]: at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127610+00:00 app[web.1]: at Validator.check (/app/node_modules/node-input-validator/lib/validator.js:203:16)
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127611+00:00 app[web.1]: at createAuditionEntryValidation (/app/dist/server/middlewares/verifyAudition.js:206:5)
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127611+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127611+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127612+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/dist/server/middlewares/verifySignUp.js:319:5
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127612+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127893+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:114) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
2022-07-17T07:10:38.127895+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:114) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Also below is the verifySignUp middleware:

```
const emailAgreementValidation = (req, res, next) => {
  let file;
  if (req.files) file = req.files.file;

  const v = new Validator(req.body, {
    email: 'required|email',
    agreement: 'required|boolean',
  });

  v.check().then((matched) => {
    if (!matched) {
      if (file) if (file.tempFilePath) deleteFile(file.tempFilePath);
      res.status(422).send(v.errors);
      return;
    }

    next();
  });
};
```

Comment: It simply means the `value` is null. You need to check why value is null. At the end of the log you can clearly see the exception is raised from `verifySignup.js` middleware.

Comment: @El. but this is running well on other platforms and this is a validation dependency that works even if the field in an object is not provided.